# Restoring of MySQL password fails and any of the Websites doesn't work

Tags: command-line, password, mysql

I use Ubuntu 16.04, Apache 2.4, and MySQL 5.7.16.

I ran the following commands to restore my lost MySQL root password, so I could login to PHPmyadmin and make backups, etc:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -uroot

    use mysql;
    update user set password=PASSWORD("HERE_I_TYPED_MY_NEW_PASSWORD") where User='root';
    flush privileges;
    quit

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

#### How I ran these exactly:

As you can see, I ran 9 commands in total. When I ran the third one, a **secondary prompt** opened, to which I pasted all 4 commands that come later (basically just as they appear above).

I then ran the last 2 commands, and from that moment not only my new password doesn't count --- I also can't surf in any of my websites --- All websites give "Database error" (even after I change their password to the new one) and I also can't login to PHPmyadmin with my new password:

#### My current problem:

When I try to login to PHPmyadmin with my "new" password (or even to force login as root without password), I get:

> 2002 - No such file or directory
> The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

I should note that I tried to stop and start the MySQL service but there was no change.

#### My question:

Is the damage irreversible and how could I get it back to normal? I found no up2date documentation on this.

#### Notes:

[I used this guide to do so](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `flush privileges` can be dangerous. You should check all your users and see if they still have the right `GRANTS` to their databases. Thay may solve the websites "Database error"

Comment: In any case, I Still can't access MySQL from root with my alleged new password, or when forcing entrance with no password from Unix root...